# printing lines using awk which have more than 3 space-delimited words?

Tags: awk

I have a file containing lines of sentences. I want to print all lines that have more than 3 words. Words are separated by whitespace.

How could I do this with `awk`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use awk like this:

```
awk 'NF>3' file
```

Answer (score 3):

#### GNU sed

```
sed -E '/\s*(\S+\s+){3}\S+/!d' file
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable NF indicates the number of fields on the current input line.

```
awk 'NF>3' file
```